# How to enforce role based accessibility for Knowledge Articles?

Tags: knowledge, role-hierarchy, articles

How to make users at specific roles be able to access knowledge articles created by the users on same roles?
For example: there are four management streams. lets say: Billing Dept, Financial Dept, Travel Desk, HR Questions.

So, users/agents belonging to Travel Desk should be able to find only travel desk related KB articles. 
How to proceed to enforce this kind of visibility?

Answer (score 1):

Data Categories can be used for this. 
We can create Data Categories for various types of articles. 
For example, Travel Desk and Financial Issues could be two Data Categories. 
We can map articles to these two data categories.

And we can set permissions for the data categories are role-level or with permission sets.